# Neo4j : Modeling Many to Many Relation

Tags: neo4j

How can i model the following data :

- "Person A" was hired by "Studio 1" to act in "Movie A"
- "Person A" was hired by "Studio 1" to act in "Movie B"
- "Person A" was hired by "Studio 1" to act in "Movie C"
- "Person A" was hired by "Studio 2" to act in "Movie X"
- "Person A" was hired by "Studio 2" to act in "Movie Y"
- "Person A" was hired by "Studio 2" to act in "Movie Z"

and then answer the question : "Person A" was hired by "Studio 1" to act in which Movies ? or find the Movies that "Person A" acted in and that was hired by "Studio 1" ?

```
1. CREATE (s1:Studio {name: 'Studio A'}),(s2:Studio {name: 'Studio B'})
2. CREATE (p:Actor {name: 'Person A'})
3. CREATE (m1:Movie {name:'Movie A'}),(m2:Movie {name:'Movie B'}),(m3:Movie {name:'Movie C'})
4. CREATE (m4:Movie {name:'Movie X'}),(m5:Movie {name:'Movie Y'}),(m6:Movie {name:'Movie Z'})
```

```
1. MATCH (A:Actor {name: 'Person A'}),(S:Studio {name: 'Studio A'}),(M:Movie {name: 'Movie A'})
 MERGE (S)-[:HIRE]->(A)-[:ACT]->(M)
2. MATCH (A:Actor {name: 'Person A'}),(S:Studio {name: 'Studio A'}),(M:Movie {name: 'Movie B'}) 
MERGE (S)-[:HIRE]->(A)-[:ACT]->(M)
3. MATCH (A:Actor {name: 'Person A'}),(S:Studio {name: 'Studio A'}),(M:Movie {name: 'Movie C'}) 
MERGE (S)-[:HIRE]->(A)-[:ACT]->(M)
```

```
4. MATCH (A:Actor {name: 'Person A'}),(S:Studio {name: 'Studio B'}),(M:Movie {name: 'Movie X'})
 MERGE (S)-[:HIRE]->(A)-[:ACT]->(M)
5. MATCH (A:Actor {name: 'Person A'}),(S:Studio {name: 'Studio B'}),(M:Movie {name: 'Movie Y'}) 
MERGE (S)-[:HIRE]->(A)-[:ACT]->(M)
6. MATCH (A:Actor {name: 'Person A'}),(S:Studio {name: 'Studio B'}),(M:Movie {name: 'Movie Z'}) 
MERGE (S)-[:HIRE]->(A)-[:ACT]->(M)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that with the current model you will lose the context about which movie the studio hired the actor to perform in. Imagine if two studios hired a single person to perform in two movies. What you will end up with is:

[image: Current graph model]

In order to not lost the context about which movie the studio hired the actor for, you could introduce an intermediary node Job for example:

[image: New graph model]

With this graph model, you don't lose the context about the movie the studio hired the person to appear in. If you need some help with the basic Cypher queries, take a look at Cypher training course: https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/training-querying-40/enrollment/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your model will fix my problem +1